# socket.io library in C

Tags: websocket, socket.io-1.0

I have already looked at some options such as [cellophane](https://github.com/ikeralbeniz/cellophane.io) but found that the sample app crashes. Also it does way more than just implement socket.io protocol because it uses json and curl. What I am looking for is a simple library in C (not c++, so no boost) which does the encoding and decoding of data using socket.io protocol, so that it can be used with any other library that does network i/o. The purpose is to implement a native client for linux developed in C to talk to node.js server.

Any libraries/solutions that would help is appreciated. Also any documentation on socket.io protocol would help, so that I can look at implementing it.

Thanks.